# TextMate restore last session/remember opened files

Tags: textmate

How do I configure TextMate text editor to remember and open tabs which were opened when when TextMate was previously run?

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I configure textMate to remember and reopen tabs when it is restarted?

Use a Project:

> **Working With Multiple Files**
>
> 2.1 Creating Projects (With Tabs)
>
> In the current version of TextMate (1.5) file tabs are only supported
>   when a project is created. Fortunately it is easy to create a project,
>   namely by selecting File → New Project (⌃⌘N).
>
> This opens a window which looks like the one below.
>
> [image: Project Window]
>
> It is possible to add files either by dragging them to the (project)
>   drawer, or use the “Add Existing Files…” action in the project drawers
>   action menu (the one with the gear icon).
>
> Another way to create a project is by dragging files directly onto the
>   TextMate application icon (shown e.g. in the dock). This is a shortcut
>   for creating a new project consisting of these files.
>
> One minor detail is that when creating a project this way, you will
>   not be asked if you want to save the project, when it is closed.
>
> The advantage of saving a project is to maintain state (e.g. which
>   files were open) and to be able to quickly re-open a particular set of
>   files. **If you leave a (saved) project open when you quit TextMate,
>   it will automatically re-open that project the next time you launch
>   TextMate.**

Source [Creating Projects (With Tabs)](https://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_multiple_files)